# Wall Drain too high?

Tags: kitchens, sink

My wall drain is barely below the bottom of my strainer basket. My T for the double kitchen sink will be below the wall drain. Will this work?

Comment: Seems like water would pool in almost all of the drain pipe under the sink which could end up being pretty smelly.  Are you replacing a shallow sink?

Answer (score 1):

Water won't flow uphill. You need to either raise the input (shallower sink) or lower the output (opening the wall and finding a way to rework the plumbing). This is why it's important to look at the drain height and counter top height plus any difference created with something like a disposal before selecting the sink depth.